# I would like to have same offset at Extrude Faces Along Normals

Tags: extrude

As like title, I would like to have same offset at Extrude Faces Along Normals..

I had searched that I can make similar deformation by make a simple E, then S + shiftZ to scale on X and Y axis,, But in this case, I can not control the offset by dimension(only by scale).

I believe I can do this because youtuber did same thing as I thought.
And reference pictures as below.

Hope you please give me a help.

(( picture#1&#2 is mine, and Picture#3 is from youtuber(using 2.9 version) ))

[[image]
[[image]
[[image]

Comment: Is it possible your object is scaled? In Object Mode, try selecting your object and pressing Ctrl+A, then clicking “Rotation & Scale”, and see if that makes the problem go away. (If not, you could also try selecting the “Offset Even” checkbox in the operation options panel, though I don’t think that should be relevant here.)

Comment: Oh my God!!! Thank you. I did not know that the meaning of Ctrl+A. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your object has been scaled in Object Mode, so even though you’re extruding an even amount in Edit Mode, after applying the object transformation, it looks uneven.

The way to fix this is generally to *apply* the object transformation, committing it to the mesh and then resetting the object transformation to zero. You can do this in Object Mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (for apply), then selecting “Rotation & Scale” from the resulting menu. Then you can go back into Edit Mode and try extruding again, which should now produce what you expect.